# how to disable RRAS on windows 2008 r2 pre-reserving blocks of IPs

Tags: windows-server-2008, dhcp, rras

I have a problem where one of the DHCP scopes has exhausted its scope of IPs. Investigating, I found that a couple of the window 2008 r2 servers were reserving blocks of IPs for RAS running on the server. We don't use RAS and or have a need.

how can this be disabled or configured to not reserve IP's automatically?

Comment: Disable RRAS? Uninstall the RRAS role?

Comment: I don't have the RRAS role installed as far as I can tell

Comment: @MikeJ You have it somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

[Uninstall the role](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469679.aspx) if you're not using it.

1. In Server Manager, under Roles Summary, click Remove roles.
2. In the Remove Roles Wizard, advance to the Remove Server Roles page.
3. Clear Network Policy and Access Services, and then click Next.
4. On the Confirm Removal Selections page, click Remove, and then click Close.
5. In the confirmation dialog box, click Yes to restart your computer.

However, if you'd like to change the way it's configured, there's a [TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469667.aspx) here.

Comment: not installed, but installing it now to see if I can configure it to not grab IP's. Odd is that I never had to do this before.

Answer (score 0):

Your RRAS server is probably set up as per the "To configure RRAS to use addresses from a DHCP server" section in this article: [Configure the Way RRAS Assigns IP Addresses to VPN Clients](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469667.aspx).

You should be able to disable DHCP from there, and hopefully that will free up the leases on your DHCP server.